# CorelDraw X7 - How to copy a group of Objects

Tags: coreldraw

This should be simple but for some reason I can't figure this out, I'm trying to copy Group named '1', I click it to highlight, click Edit->Copy, click Group named 'Right' and finally click Edit->Paste and nothing happens, why is this, this should be trivial but I just can't get it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pasting directly in group 'Right' is not possible.
However if you paste with group 'Right' selected, it should paste on the active layer.
If this doesn't happen, there might be something corrupted in your install of Corel...
Could be a bug in X7?
I use X6 16.4.1.1281 and this pasting works fine.